# What are dimensions of co-ordinates which are used to define an electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, units, dimensional-analysis

A possible electrostatic field is:

$ E_x = 6xy$

$ E_y = 3x^2-3y^2$

$ E_z = 0$

Suppose we are using SI system. So unit for components of field is volts/meter.

Then what are dimensions of $x$ and $y$ in above expressions ? We know that electrostatic field is a function of space co-ordinates, here $x$ and $y$. So in SI system, $x$ and $y$ are measured in meters. So RHS of field components are in meter-square ($m^2$).

So LHS is in volts/meter while RHS is in meter-square.

I am sure there is some fallacy in my arguments, but I don't know what is that.

Comment: The numbers you have give have no dimensions. But if you derive from first principles, that is to say from a charge distribution and arrive at this, the numbers are the ones most likely to carry the dimensions that would make the equation dimensionally correct. Nevertheless, where did you get this equation from (source) ?

Comment: @user35952: I got this field expression from famous Berkeley Physics Course Vol.2 by Purcell; chapter 2

Comment: Alright ! I am surprised, that they haven't specified anything, may be they took it to be trivial and understood easily. So as one of the answer suggests, the dimension is hidden inside the numbers !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constants in your expressions secretly contain units. You can determine what they are algebraically. For example considering the dimensions (denoted with [square brackets]) of $E_x$:

$$
\textrm{[units of $E_x$]} = \textrm{[units of 6]} \textrm{[units of $x$]} \textrm{[units of $y$]} ,
$$
$$
\textrm{[V/m]} = \textrm{[units of 6]} \textrm{[m]} \textrm{[m]}.
$$

This is one of the (many) reasons to solve problems symbolically in physics and only put in numbers at the end.

Comment: Then units for number 6 will be $V/m^3$. Correct?

Comment: Yes. You can get the units of the "3"s in $E_y$ similarly, and the units will be different from the units of the "6". It's unfortunately pretty common for intro level textbooks to omit units in this way which can lead to unnecessary confusion.